# Como usar setNextFocusableComponent em um JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Eu usei `setNextFocusableComponent` em um `JTextArea`, porem não funciona pelo fato do TAB funcionar como um "espaço" dentro do `JTextArea`, como resolver isso ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> para mudar o foco de uma `JTextArea` para outros componentes. Por padrão, o `TAB` insere espaços de tabulação dentro deste componente.

Mas nada impede de se alterar este comportamento padrão, adicionando um [**`KeyAdapter`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) para "forçar" mudar de foco ao clicar `TAB`. Retirei este exemplo abaixo [deste site](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-move-focus-from-jtextarea-using-tab-key/):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TextAreaTabMoveFocus extends JFrame {
    public TextAreaTabMoveFocus() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        setSize(300, 300);
        setTitle("JTextArea TAB DEMO");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField();
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        // Add key listener to change the TAB behavior in
        // JTextArea to transfer focus to other component forward
        // or backward.
        textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
                    if (e.getModifiers() > 0) {
                        textArea.transferFocusBackward();
                    } else {
                        textArea.transferFocus();
                    }
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });

        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(passwordField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TextAreaTabMoveFocus().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]